# How to remove extra layer in JSON data from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, firebase

I'm trying to use Underscore.js to get some data from the JSON returned from Firebase but there are a lot of null values returned.  The JSON being returned from Firebase currently looks like this:

```
{
 "-JFnc68gIRFohkWKBP05":
{
 "date":"2014-02-15T03:39:16.954Z",
 "description":"Thanks so much!",
 "name":"Rob",
 "role":"Give"
},
 "-JFncNSO4G_hNm0YySTA":
{
 "date":"2014-02-15T03:40:27.858Z",
 "description":"This is fun!",
 "name":"Cobie",
 "role":"Received"
},
 "-JFrhlpgCWxJnDETM1gg":
{
 "date":"2014-02-15T22:42:31.013Z",
 "description":"Brought over some really delicious cookies",
 "name":"John Smith",
 "role":"Gave"
},
 "-JFrjHlV-fsOVHyTXHZJ":
{
 "date":"2014-02-15T22:49:08.448Z",
 "description":"Charles was wonderfully patient.",
 "name":"Charles Darwin",
 "role":"Received"
 },
 "-JFsWZPbL6_j-9nQwP29":
{
 "date":"2014-02-16T02:28:47.950Z",
 "description":"On the Origin of Species... yaddi daddi da....",
 "name":"Charles Darwin",
 "role":"Gave"
},
"-JFsWdH61Y-I01-rqn_n":
{
 "date":"2014-02-16T02:29:07.887Z",
 "description":"Let me off to do my computer work without bugging me.",
 "name":"Cobie",
 "role":"Gave"
}
}
```

When I use Underscore.js to extract data, these are samples of how it comes out:

javascript:

> ```
>   $scope.allNames = _.pluck($scope.data, 'name');
> ```

output:

> ["","","","","","","","","","","","Rob","Cobie","John Smith","Charles Darwin","Charles Darwin","Cobie"]

javascript:

> $scope.something = _.groupBy(userRef, 'userRef.name');

output:

> {"undefined":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{"date":"2014-02-15T03:39:16.954Z","description":"Thanks so much!","name":"Rob","rating":5,"role":"Give"},{"date":"2014-02-15T03:40:27.858Z","description":"This is fun!","name":"Cobie","rating":4,"role":"Received"},{"date":"2014-02-15T22:42:31.013Z","description":"Brought over some really delicious cookies","name":"John Smith","rating":3,"role":"Gave"},{"date":"2014-02-15T22:49:08.448Z","description":"Charles was wonderfully patient.","name":"Charles Darwin","rating":"2","role":"Received"},{"date":"2014-02-16T02:28:47.950Z","description":"On the Origin of Species... yaddi daddi da....","name":"Charles Darwin","role":"Gave"},{"date":"2014-02-16T02:29:07.887Z","description":"Let me off to do my computer work without bugging me.","name":"Cobie","role":"Gave"}]}

How do I get deep enough into the JSON to not return the nulls? Or, If there is a better way to remove the headers from the JSON entirely?

Comment: which version of `Underscore.js` o you use?

Comment: 1.6.0.  I just grabbed the js file off the official site today.

Comment: I tested you code in `underscorejs.org` with chrome console, but the my output was:`["Rob","Cobie","John Smith","Charles Darwin","Charles Darwin","Cobie"]`

Comment: Sorry, there's an additional layer on tip of all that's shown. Its more like this(android phone won't let me do a return): SOMETHING {
 "-JFnc68gIRFohkWKBP05":
{
 "date":"2014-02-15T03:39:16.954Z",
 "description":"Thanks so much!",
 "name":"Rob",
 "role":"Give"
},
 "-JFncNSO4G_hNm0YySTA":
{
 "date":"2014-02-15T03:40:27.858Z",
 "description":"This is fun!",
 "name":"Cobie",
 "role":"Received"
},
 "-JFrhlpgCWxJnDETM1gg":
{
 "date":"2014-02-15T22:42:31.013Z",
 "description":"Brought over some really delicious cookies",
 "name":"John Smith",
 "role":"Gave"
}, ...

Comment: Back on a computer. This is how it looks:

Comment: I also can't repro this. Please include the "additional layer" in the code examples embedded within your question.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue with first removing the empty strings using underscore's _.without function.

```
$scope.allcontacts = _.without(messy_contacts, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*underscore compact*](http://underscorejs.org/#compact) for this.

$scope.allcontacts = _.compact(messy_contacts);